# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre esta condición 'if (value % 4 == 0)' y esta 'if (value % 4 == 0 and value % 100 != 0) or (value % 400 == 0)'?

Tags: python

Parece fácil, a simple vista podríamos decir que simplemente hay más condicionales.
Esta es el código:

```
def es_bisiesto():

    value = int(input("Enter Year"))
    if (value % 4 == 0):
       print(f"{type(value)} es un año bisiesto.")
    else:
      print(f"{value} no es un año bisiesto.")

es_bisiesto()

def bisiesto():
    value = int(input("Enter Year"))
    if (value % 4 == 0 and value % 100 != 0) or (value % 400 == 0):
       print(f"{type(value)} es un año bisiesto.")
    else:
      print(f"{type(value)} no es un año bisiesto.")
bisiesto()
```

¿Por qué si ingreso el valor '1800', la función es_bisiesto() me da 'Es un año bisiesto', y la función bisiesto() me da como resultado 'No es bisiesto?
¿Tendrá que ver por como funciona el Módulo(%)?

Estoy en python, y quizás es por eso que no lo entiendo, quizá en C hay algo más lógico.
No se si esto sirva: PEP-1 HOL-56

Comment: No se si tu pregunta está bien enfocada. Evidentemente darán resultados distintos, dado que la condición para cada función es distinta. `1800 % 4 es cero` y `1800 % 400` es distinto a cero, por que lógicamente no entra en esa condición

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No tiene nada que ver con como funciona el operador módulo en Python, es que son algoritmos diferentes y el primer algoritmo no es estrictamente correcto de acuerdo a como el calendario Gregoriano intenta corregir una realidad astronómica:

- La Tierra rota sobre su eje aproximadamente 365.2422 veces al año (año solar/tropical).
- Un año "normal" de nuestro calendario tiene 365 días.

Si no se corrige, terminamos con un desfase por esos 0.2422 días que nos "sobran" cada año. Para corregirlo en lo posible, hay ciertas reglas:

- Agregamos un día cada cuatro años (año bisiesto), lo cual se aproxima bastante, ya que eso promedia 365.25 días al año ( 1461 días / 4 años), pero no son esos 365.2422... El error acumulado hace que cada 100 años se equivoque aproximadamente por un año de más, por lo que agregamos otra regla.
- Cada 100 años, un año que debería ser bisiesto no lo es y con eso nos da un promedio de 365.24 días al año (36524 días / 100 años), más cerca pero aun así...
- Cada 400 años uno de esos años que no seria bisiesto según la regla anterior es bisiesto esta vez. Con esto nos aproximamos a 365.2425 días por año (146097 días / 400 años), lo cual está mas cerca de la realidad astronómica.

Aunque sigue siendo imperfecto (deja un desfase de algo menos de medio minuto cada año), nos conformamos con ello... o mas bien es difícil de corregir aplicando reglas como las anteriores por otras razones físicas ajenas al calendario mismo. Para empezar el tiempo que dura un día no es constante, las fricciones de marea que ejerce la Luna, acoplamientos núcleo-manto o cambios de distribución de masas en el planeta como las glaciaciones modifican la velocidad de rotación. El tiempo que tarda en orbitar el Sol, aunque mas estable también varia. Se calcula que para dentro de 2000 años tendremos que quitar un día para corregir la desaceleración, si es que seguimos en el planeta...

El segundo algoritmo simplemente refleja lo anterior, un año es bisiesto si:

- Es divisible entre 4 pero no entre 100  (`value % 4 == 0 and value % 100 != 0`) o bien
- Es divisible entre 400 (`value % 400 == 0`)

El primer algoritmo solo tiene en cuenta la primera regla para corregir el desfase, pero no las otras dos. 1800 al igual que 2100 no son bisiestos porque se les aplica la segunda regla, pero si lo fue el 2000 (tercera regla). La primera función básicamente da como bisiestos años que no lo son, todos aquellos a los que se les aplica la segunda regla.

---

Aunque no influye para nada en este caso, dado que lo mencionas, si que existen diferencias en como el operador `%` funciona en Python y en C. Esto se debe a que C usa truncado y el operador `%` en Python usa la función suelo a la hora de definir el cociente de la división. En cambio, `math.fmod` usa truncado y `math.remainder` redondeo tal como ocurre en sus contrapartidas en C/C++:

```
>>> import math

>>> 10 % 3.5
3.0
>>> 10 % -3.5
-0.5
>>> -10 % 3.5
0.5
>>> -10 % -3.5
-3.0

>>> math.fmod(10, 3.5)
3.0
>>> math.fmod(10, -3.5)
3.0
>>> math.fmod(-10, 3.5)
-3.0
>>> math.fmod(-10, -3.5)
-3.0

>>> math.remainder(10, 3.5)
-0.5
>>> math.remainder(10, -3.5)
-0.5
>>> math.remainder(-10, 3.5)
0.5
>>> math.remainder(-10, -3.5)
0.5
```

En caso de que tanto divisor como dividendo tengan el mismo signo no hay discrepancia entre el operador % de Python y `math.fmod` (o su contrapartida de C/C++), pero difieren cuando tienen signo distinto.

Dado que en nuestro caso ambos operandos son positivos nada difiere, el modulo simplemente nos sirve para comprobar si el año es divisible entre 4, 100 y 400 respectivamente (resto de la división euclidia es cero) o no lo son (resto diferente de cero).